# Why doesn't the alert execute?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, alert

I have a control if a review already exist, if it exist I want to warn the visitor that if the person click OK/yes in the alert the review will be overwritten, if the person press no/cancel the review will not be updated. But it doesn't work, in the debugging the alert line just passes by and updates without any alert.

```
if (ReviewExist(StoreID, UserID) != 0)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Message", "confirm('Are you sure?');", true);
    UpdateStoreReview(Description);
    Response.Redirect("Default");
}
else      
{
    AddStoreReview(Description);
}
```

Comment: The example from [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y.aspx) wraps the js in `<script></script>` tags. Have you tried that?

Comment: Even if things worked as you expected (i.e. that the client script executed before proceeding to the next line), note that you're not (nor are you able to) checking the result of your `confirm()` call...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is because your `Response.Redirect` redirects the control to another page which will ignore your `RegisterScript`.

What you need to do is, if you are trying to acheive this in the button click (update button),  then in the Page_Load try

```
if(!IsPostBack)    
{
 btnUpdate.Attributes.Add("OnClick","confirm('Are you sure?');");
}
```

Then the above code can be changed to

```
if (ReviewExist(StoreID, UserID) != 0)
{
    UpdateStoreReview(Description);
    Response.Redirect("Default");
}
else      
{
    AddStoreReview(Description);
}
```

**Note**
I think you need to redirect to Default.aspx; but you are missing .aspx in the `response.redirect`.

Comment: Okey, but I only want the user to see the alert if the user already posted a review. It looks like every time the button is pressed the alert will appear or am I wrong?

Comment: That you can add an If statement before adding btnUpdate.Attributes.Add which will check if user already added a review

Answer (score 2):

You need the script tags in your script.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Message", "<script type='text/javascript'>confirm('Are you sure?');</script>", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

IF you  using the ASP.net

```
<asp:Button ID="_btnSalvar" runat="server" Confirm="False" ConfirmType="None" Text="Are you sure?" Width="131px" OnClick="_btnSalvar_Click" />
```